# AFNetworking - json file uploading on iOS

Tags: ios, file-upload, afnetworking

I am starting to grow grey hairs here:-)

I have this code, which was based from an image upload - which there are so many of on the web, but I need it to upload a .json file - the file generates correctly to appear in my Documents Directory, but I need it to be uploaded to my server.

```
        _myJSON= [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"{ \" %@ \" : [ ", _menuCategoryPickerFld.text];

[_myJSON appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"{ \"name\" : \"%@\", \"model\" : \"%@\", \"size\" : \"%@\" }",
                        _menuTitlePickerFld.text, _menuSubTitlePickerFld.text, _menuPricePickerFld.text]];

[_myJSON appendString: @" ]}"];

NSData *data = [_myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testJSON2.json"];
[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];


NSString *tempString = @"http://thepalmsmarket.co.nz/jsonExports/uploads/";

NSURL *remoteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tempString];

// Back to NSData
NSData *convertedFile = [_myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:remoteURL];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:convertedFile];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
{


}];
[operation start];
```

Ok so I think some of the formatting is wrong, but also for files to be uploaded don't I need to add the username and password of my web-server in my app somewhere, so it can be authenticated for the upload??